# Android animated GIF

Tags: android, webview, gif, animated

I'm trying to display animated GIF using WebView. It works fine on most devices, but still some of them doesn't support animations and a static GIF is displayed.

How can I detect if the device supports animated GIFs in WebView, so I can display appropriate message if it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this seams to be [a common issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422). There are some workarounds posted in the Bug-report, but it seams that it's not an Android Core-feature.

Some company's (like HTC) maybe took care of this themselves, but you can't rely on animated gif's to work.

Comment: I know I can't, that's why I've asked how to check whether they are supported on current device.

Comment: Well, if the solution provided by @Prios_KR isn't enough, I'm afraid there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see with this link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422.
this issue still unresolved for two yrs.
But the most of the devices work fine in Gingerbread. So you might check the OS level (starting in level 9) which is works or not

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a reliable way to check whether current device actually supports animated GIFs. A solution that "works most of the time" isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it this way, but its the most effective way to find out. Open a GIF image, and if it doesnt play... Its not supported on the device

Comment: Doesn't really help in this case :p

Answer (score 0):

Animated GIF support was added to Android in version 2.2.  If you check the version using [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html), it should tell you whether the GIFs are working.

Comment: I've received reports from people using 2.2 that GIFs aren't working.

Comment: This answer is invalid. There are some Android 2.1 phones with GIF support enabled by manufacturer and there are some Android 2.3 phones with no GIF support at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android C++ file `external/webkit/WebCore/platform/graphics/android/ImageSourceAndroid.cpp` there is a function `static bool should_use_animated_gif(int width, int height)` which returns `true` if `ANDROID_LARGE_MEMORY_DEVICE` is defined.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-review/0V8aUdyeA7I), Leon Scroggins (seems to be a Google engineer) says that `ANDROID_LARGE_MEMORY_DEVICE` is defined "for all arm devices with a VFP, and all non-arm devices."

Edit: This is confirmed by `external/webkit/Android.mk`:

```
ifeq ($(ARCH_ARM_HAVE_VFP),true)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_LARGE_MEMORY_DEVICE
endif
```

In my understanding, all ArmV7 cpus do have a VFP, so animated GIFs should work on modern cpus with ArmV7.