# Android animated GIF support

Tags: android, gif, animated

How can I check if current device supports animated GIF files? Checking OS version isn't reliable, because some Android 2.1 phones have enabled support and there are phones with 2.3 which do not support GIF files.

Comment: Please see this thread on animated gif's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android animated GIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713384/android-animated-gif)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the only backwards compatible solution i can think of right now is just get all frames from the gif and animate it yourself in a view.

check out this question to do so:
[Split GIF into frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312699/split-gif-into-frames)

Comment: Please read the question again. I didn't ask how to play GIF files on older devices. I've asked how to RELIABLY check whether device supports them. I've got no idea who upvoted your answer.