# Detect browser support of animated GIF images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animated-gif

Some mobile browsers do not support animated GIF images.

Is it possible to run some JavaScript/jQuery function that would detect if the browser supports animation GIFs or not?

Comment: You can use Modernizr.

Comment: Other than checking for specific devices, there's no way to know if the browser supports animated GIFs. @AliGajani Can you point out documentation showing that Modernizr can detect this?

Comment: @Joe [old Android versions, apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713384/android-animated-gif)

Comment: In Firefox you can set `image.animation_mode` to disable GIF animations, I doubt Modernizr will detect that

Comment: What about dectect if gif is animated ? https://gist.github.com/lakenen/3012623

Answer (score 0):

There is no script that will determine if the browser can render animated GIF's.  What you will need to do is run a user agent check to determine the browser type and version, and then you could check that against a list of animated gif supporting browsers.

A quick googling doesn't turn up an exact listing, but you should be able to determine this pretty easily. It might be easier to compile a list of browsers that do NOT support them. Non-graphical browsers like lynx, older browsers and some mobile browsers..